# Work with HTML coder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails backend developer and I am now working in a team with an HTML coder and I have some problems with information exchange.

I want him to generate all the HTML templates (haml, erb, whatever) and css files. But he has actually no clue on how to install ruby (and rails).

So, we are working now in this ugly workcycle when he puts all html's and css's in public, test them, and then I (myself) move them to correct place.

Is there a tool (for HTML codes) that mimics Rails rendering part so he will run this tool, which must be easy, and when the server starts, he can put all the templates to `app/` and test them?

I see this as a small easy installable subset of rails, that only deal with page rendering.

Answer (score 1):

If your coder still doesn't know how to install ruby or how to configure stuff for works , then I can say this is quite problematic . You either can try any cloud based IDE . Or , tools like git to get only raw stuff.

But , you also can look for someone who in minimum way will try to make the whole process possible by learning and installing ruby in their pc .

Comment: On the one side, you are true, but on the other side "HTML coding" skill is no way related with rails. This guy was working with Django before, and he knows how to set up Django. Now he needs to learn how to install rails, although it does not give him any advantages in HTML coding skills

Comment: That means ... this guy is quite has potential . And can earn trust from people . Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem where a copywriter needed to play with the html and we ended up using [Cloud9](https://c9.io/).
Cloud9 is a collaborative IDE in the cloud, IMHO It's pretty decent for small scale projects and can really get the job done.
I simply installed rails once and ran a local dev server and she did all the modifications and watced the preview.
Another option is to create a [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) environment and preisntall rails there. This means the HTML coder would have to install a VM on his machine and run the vagrant there.

Comment: IMHO vagrant is just increase of complexity for the coder. Now he needs not only to install rails, but also vagrant =)

Comment: I agree, this is why Cloud9 was my first suggestion, you can install any prerequisites on it by yourself and hand it over to the HTML coder.